# Cannot Combine Fragment and Activity login

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-studio

I just started with fragments and want to learn how to do more functional app with sliding menu but I get error on `setcontentview` because I want to make a login screen which is an activity.
links to my tutorials.
slide menu:
[android sliding menu](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)
and login screen:
[android login and register](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

```
public class LoginActivity extends Fragment {
public LoginActivity() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
private static final String TAG = RegisterActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private Button btnLogin;
private Button btnLinkToRegister;
private EditText inputEmail;
private EditText inputPassword;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private SessionManager session;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);

    inputEmail = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLinkToRegister = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToRegisterScreen);

    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginMainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Login button Click Event
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            // Check for empty data in the form
            if (email.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                // login user
                checkLogin(email, password);
            } else {
                // Prompt user to enter credentials
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter the credentials!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

    });

    // Link to Register Screen
    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * function to verify login details in mysql db
 * */
private void checkLogin(final String email, final String password) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_login";

    pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
    showDialog();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();

            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    // Create login session
                    session.setLogin(true);

                    // Launch main activity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            LoginMainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // Error in login. Get the error message
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } `
```

I get error at: -`setContentView`,

```
- pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this); 
- session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());
-           Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginMainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
```

Comment: Hi @Sh4rk162, it's hard to help you because we need to follow links to get to your code (what if the link goes down, or it's blocked by a firewall, etc.?), then find the code you have a problem with. Can you post the relevant parts of your code which cause you the problem? See "[*How do I ask a good question*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for some tips - in particular the section "[*How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)".

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant "could you edit your question to include the code?" If you post it as a comment it's better, but there's no formatting (line breaks, etc.) so it's hard to read. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mixed an `Activity` and a `Fragment`. If you use `setContentView`, then you have to extend an `Activity`.
Also you get an error here:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            LoginMainActivity.class);
```

because the `LoginActivity` is a fragment.
Also, here

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
```

change `getApplicationContext` to `LoginActivity.this` after changing the superclass of `LoginActivity` to `Activity`.

Comment: i know, thats the problem, im trying to solve this for 1 day now and so far no fix.

Comment: Just change the `LoginActivity extends Fragment` to `LoginActivity extends Activity`.  If you are going to make a `LoginActivity` a `Fragment`, this code will not work, because there are lots of things to change.

Comment: is there any other way to make login screen in fragments without changing whole code?

Comment: Hm... Ok. You need to use `onCreateView` instead of `onCreate` here.

Comment: Then, instead of `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_login);` change to `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);`

Comment: Then use `rootView. findViewById()` to find the views.

Comment: `pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);` - here you need `getActivity()` instead of `this`

Comment: Here: `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LoginMainActivity.class);` use `getActivity()` instead of `LoginActivity.this`, then `getActivity().startActivity(intent);` and `getActivity().finish()`

Comment: The same is for this block of code: `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    RegisterActivity.class);`

Comment: And this block of code: `Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            LoginMainActivity.class);`

Comment: I'm not sure about `SessionManager`. If it is OK to use an application context here, then it's OK. If no, then you''' probably need to change it to `getActivity()` instead of `getApplicationContext`

Comment: I forgot... in `onCreateView`, in the end, return `rootView`.